# Second part of an IF statement for Dropbox oauth athentication isn't triggered

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dropbox

I tried a simple if statement to avoid having to run the code below on every pageload, but the second part with `dropbox_authStatus === 1` is not triggered although `alert("authStatus: "+dropbox_authStatus);` tells me that dropbox_authStatus is 1. What's wrong with my code?

```
$('document').ready(function() {

dropbox_authStatus = localStorage.getItem('dropbox_authstatus');
alert("authstatus: "+dropbox_authStatus);

if(!dropbox_authStatus) {
    localStorage.setItem('dropbox_authstatus',1);   
    //initialization
    var client = new Dropbox.Client({
        key: "hm4c58qp6rpysot", secret: "w7cdx6o8p2hyubj"
    });
    alert("initialized");
    //preset driver to the dropbox page
    client.authDriver(new Dropbox.Drivers.Redirect());
    //authentication
    client.authenticate(function(error, client) {
        if (error) {
            return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
        }
    });
} else if (dropbox_authStatus === 1) {
    localStorage.setItem('dropbox_authstatus',2);   
    //initialization
    var client = new Dropbox.Client({
        key: "hm4c58qp6rpysot", secret: "w7cdx6o8p2hyubj"
    });
    alert("continued");
    //preset driver to the dropbox page
    client.authDriver(new Dropbox.Drivers.Redirect());
    //authentication
    client.authenticate(function(error, client) {
        if (error) {
            return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
        }
        client.getUserInfo(function(error, userInfo) {
            if (error) {
                return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
            }

            alert("hello: "+userInfo.name);

        });
    });
    //Save Dropbox credentials
    localStorage.setItem('dropbox_auth', JSON.stringify(client.credentials()));
    alert("credentials saved:"+JSON.stringify(client.credentials()));
}
});
```

Thanks in advance! The code inside the if-statements mainly belongs to the dropbox.js library hosted on github: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/doc/getting_started.md

Comment: Maybe `dropbox_authStatus` is a string, and not a number?

Comment: That's it! I replaced the numbers by descriptions of the athentication process and it works. Thanks for the fast answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer derived from comments on original question**

I'm just guessing, but if the log seems correct, but the condition isn't met, maybe `dropbox_authStatus` is a string instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of dropbox.js support an `interactive: false` option on the `client.authenticate()` method. You can use this public API to achieve the same goal, and your code won't break on library updates.

Code snippet: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/doc/snippets.md#sign-into-dropbox-button

authenticate documentation: http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#authenticate-instance